# Loop Query to check if result doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

So far I've got the following:

```
SELECT u1.Email, u2.Email, f.HomeTeam, f.AwayTeam, f.Date
FROM Fixtures f
INNER JOIN Users u1 ON f.HomeTeam = u1.TeamID
INNER JOIN Users u2 ON f.AwayTeam = u2.TeamID
WHERE IsResult = 0
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Results WHERE (TeamID = f.HomeTeam OR TeamID = f.AwayTeam) AND FixtureID = f.FixtureID)
AND Status = 1
AND Date <= CURDATE()
ORDER BY Date
```

Essentially I need to check all fixtures in the Fixtures table, and check to see if they've got a result for both teams in the Results table and then get the email from the user who hasn't submitted a result.

Tables are:

Users:

```
UserID | TeamID | Email
```

Teams:

```
TeamID | TeamName
```

Fixtures:

```
FixtureID | HomeTeam | AwayTeam | Date | Status | IsResult
```

Results:

```
ResultID | FixtureID | TeamID
```

With the current query, it's returning rows where the fixture doesn't have a result added from either team. What I really need to do is for it to return the email of the users who's team has **NOT** submitted a result.

EDIT:

Thought I was getting somewhere using the following by cycling each user, and then team:

```
SELECT u.Email, u.UserID, u.TeamID, f.Date, f.HomeTeam, f.AwayTeam,     
f.FixtureID
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Teams t ON t.TeamID u.TeamID
INNER JOIN Fixtures f ON f.HomeTeam = t.TeamID
WHERE IsResult = 0
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Results 
WHERE TeamID = u.TeamID AND FixtureID = f.FixtureID)
AND Status = 1
AND Date <= CURDATE()
ORDER BY Date
```

However whilst it starts off well, when there is a game that both teams haven't entered a result in, it only returns for one manager.

Comment: I would drive from results establishing which fixture has a teamid count of 1.

Comment: @P.Salmon I had considered that, but also need to count which fixtures have a TeamID count of 0 though.

Comment: That's a contradiction of the last paragraph in the  question.

Comment: No, I don't think it is, but sorry if it's confusing. I need it to return the email of users who's team has not submitted a result. There will be instances where BOTH teams have not submitted a result and instances where one of the teams has.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was getting somewhere. Just realised I was only looking for home teams.

```
SELECT u.Email, u.UserID, u.TeamID, f.Date, f.HomeTeam, f.AwayTeam, f.FixtureID
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Fixtures f ON (f.HomeTeam = u.TeamID OR f.AwayTeam = u.TeamID)
WHERE IsResult = 0
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Results WHERE TeamID = u.TeamID AND FixtureID = f.FixtureID)
AND f.Status = 1
AND f.Date <= CURDATE()
ORDER BY f.Date
```

Seems to work!